# Probability and Dice

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose that I roll a six sided die $x$ times, say 10, what is the probability that I will get a particular side/number, say 6, a specific number of times? Is there a general formula to compute this?

For example, what is the probability that I will:

- Get exactly 1 time six
- Get exactly 2 times six
- Get exactly 3 times six
- $\dots$
- Get exactly 10 times six

Answer (score 2):

It's a binary outcome for each, correct? Either you have a success (ie. roll a six), or you have a failure (ie. roll a 'not six').  Your probability of success is $\frac{1}{6}$, and you can decide your number of trials $n$, and number of successes, $k$ for which you want to calculate an answer.  Here's the wikipedia description of a binomial distribution.  That should get you where you're going.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution